# Shortcut for folder without address bar [Windows 10]

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, shortcuts, address-bar

Is there a way to create a shortcut for a folder to open Windows Explorer without address bar?

Comment: There is no native way to do this so far as I know. The address bar has been an integral part of Windows Explorer for as far back as I looked (Windows 7).

Comment: How about goto the folder and dragging the folder (while holding the right mouse button) and creating a shortcut on the Deskop?